# Determining filename via HEAD request of an fpURL

Tags: filepicker.io

I wanted to confirm that the "proper" way to retrieve the filename of an uploaded item was by snagging the "x-file-name" header when doing a HEAD on the fpURL. That is what I discovered, but didn't see this documented anywhere. Just want to make sure this is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we set this header so that you can get the filename off the headers of the fpURL. A cleaner way to do it would be to use the /metadata endpoint, i.e. https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/5qYoopVTsixCJJiqSWSE/metadata

Comment: Hey -- that's pretty useful. Where is that documented?

Comment: Our "REST"-y api that the javascript library uses could use some better documentation, currently a lot of it is documented under https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/#fpurl